# Is there something like a URI for USB devices?

Tags: usb, uri, protocols, specifications, urn

I'm wondering if there is a specification around to address USB devices like:

usb://...

Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that there isn't. Why should there be such a thing for USB devices when there isn't for any other type of attached device? And anyway, the computer treats USB devices as the specific class of device that they represent (i.e., a printer, a scanner, attached storage, etc.), not all as generic USB devices.

Comment: I have to make things a little bit more concrete.
We have a device that can be connected RS232, Ethernet and two different USB interfaces.
My whish would be to have an interface like:
Connect(String uri),
Send, ...
Based on the uri a factory could instanciate the proper communication layer.

I haven't found anything like a USB URI but I thought I ask before I invent my own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is a URN format which any device which supports the Universal Plug-and-Play protocol can use to advertise its capabilities:

> When a device is added to the network, it multicasts discovery messages to advertise its root device, any embedded devices, and any services.

For example:

- urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:deviceType:v
- urn:schemas-microsoft-com:device:MediaCenterExtenderMFD:1
- urn:schemas-wifialliance-org:device:WFADevice:1
- urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1
- urn:wifialliance-org:serviceId:
- urn:microsoft-com:serviceId:NULL
- urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower:1

**References**

- [Remote Experience Advertisement Protocol: Appendix B: UPnP Device Description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee781144.aspx)
- [Writing a UPnP Service](https://developer.gnome.org/gupnp/stable/server-tutorial.html)
- [RFC 7255: Using the International Mobile station Equipment Identity (IMEI) Uniform Resource Name (URN) as an Instance ID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7255)
- [WFA Device 1.0 (pdf)](https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wfa-device-10-template-101)
- [UPnP Technical Basics: UPnP Device Architecture (UDA) (pdf)](http://upnp.org/resources/documents/UPnP_UDA_tutorial_July2014.pdf)
- [Nodejs implementation of the UPnP Device Architecture 1.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peer-upnp)
- [Zoltan Balazs: The real risks of the IoT security nightmare (pdf)](https://camp.hsbp.org/2016/pp7e0/fahrplan/system/attachments/10/original/Zoltan_Balazs_HITBGSEC_jav.pdf)
- [Learning IoT Security: Jan 2016 (pdf)](http://iot.ieee.org/images/files/pdf/LearningIoTSecurityJan2016.pdf)
- [Accenture Security Call to Action: IoT PoV (pdf)](https://www.accenture.com/t00010101T000000__w__/au-en/_acnmedia/Accenture/Conversion-Assets/Microsites/Documents22/Accenture-Security-Call-to-Action-IOT-PoV-FINAL-WEB2.PDF)
- [The QName URN Namespace](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-rsalz-qname-urn-00.html)
- [URIs, URLs, and URNs: Clarifications and Recommendations 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/)
- [URL vs. URI vs. URN, in More Concise Terms | Damnhandy](https://damnhandy.com/2009/08/26/url-vs-uri-vs-urn-in-more-concise-terms/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Per [`kcmshell5 kcm_printer_manager`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt7to.png), literally `usb://`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.hardware.usb.usbaccessory.uri?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13&viewFallbackFrom=xamarin-android-sdk-9 may additionally provide USB URIs, but I have not evaluated it.